# POST Using AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios, json, post, afnetworking

In my application I am using AFNetworking 2.0 for
posting some JSON data to server below is the code snippet

```
[myAFHTTPSessionManager POST:@"addpatient" parameters:patientDic success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"suce %@ %@",task.response, responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failure: %@",error);
    }];
```

here 'patientDic' is an NSDictionary containing the values to post 
But I encounter the below error message

'Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x10e55380 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://OurService/addpatient, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404), NSUnderlyingError=0x10e55430 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html'

to get rid of the error (unacceptable content-type: text/html') I set the Request serializer to `[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]`
But still getting the same error
Help me if I am missing something

Comment: it's correct url http:/OurService/addpatient?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the data you are posting, but it is telling you the URL you are posting to does not exist: `http://OurService/addpatient`. This seems like a very unlikely valid URL.

Comment: Also you can try this myAFHTTPSessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [requestManagerToServer.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

Comment: @СергейОлейнич thanks for the comment I will check....